# TAG Audio preload

Tags: html5, áudio

Olá! Estou empacado num problema e gostaria de uma ajuda. Tenho conhecimento bem limitado e desde já agradeço demais.

Preciso carregar uma lista de áudios para tocar ao mesmo tempo, como um Mixer, mas estou com problema de sincronismo, pois as faixas não carregam ao mesmo tempo, causando um delay.

```html
<div class='audio-container' name='Audio' preload="auto">
<audio name="audio1" url="audio/audio1.mp3"></audio>
<audio name="audio2" url="audio/audio2.mp3"></audio>
<audio name="audio3" url="audio/audio3.mp3"></audio> 
</div>
```

O preload="auto" não funciona muito bem, pois a lista de áudios é bem maior. A ideia é ter uma barra de carregamento, informando o "download" de cada faixa. É possível?

Mais uma vez muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Sergio, Achei um link ([Tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060642/preload-multiple-audio-files/31466457)) no stack overflow americano , ele mostra como utilizar o preload com múltiplos arquivos de audio, pode ser que alguma informação de lá possa te ajudar. Abraços.

Comment: Poizé. Também achei esse tópico e to aqui queimando a mufa em cima dele. Tenho conhecimento bem limitado, mas to tentando. Muito obrigado pela ajuda Gustavo! Abração!